# Receiving NULL when trying to create display Display Stream (CGDisplayStreamCreateWithDispatchQueue)

Tags: macos, core-graphics, video-capture

I'm trying to do some screen capturing on Mac OS using the standard CGDisplayStreamCreateWithDispatchQueue API, however I keep getting a NULL stream Ref when I call the API, and there is apparently no error information so I can't figure ut why it is failing.

I have tried code from these two sources (with minor tweaks when needed):

[Capture screen with CGDisplayStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017895/capture-screen-with-cgdisplaystream)
https://github.com/diederickh/screen_capture/blob/master/src/test/test_mac_api_research.m

I have also tried CGDisplayStreamCreate(), and using a variety of resolutions and pixel formats. I have also confirmed CGGetActiveDisplayList is returning back one CGDirectDisplayID which I am passing to the API call.

Can anyone suggest what might be causing this silent failure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. It appears either I had accidentally clicked 'No' to the screen sharing permissions, or it hadn't come up. In any case, using the command in this question I was able to reset things and now it works.

[How to trigger screen recording permission system modal dialog on macOS Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57957198/how-to-trigger-screen-recording-permission-system-modal-dialog-on-macos-catalina)